# in Haskell, how to replace elements of a pair in the presence of Maybe values?

Tags: haskell, monads, traversable

Consider these two functions in Haskell:

```
replace_snd :: b -> Maybe (a, b) -> Maybe (a, b)
replace_snd y' (Just (x, y)) = Just (x, y')
replace_snd _ Nothing = Nothing

inject_snd :: Maybe b -> (a, b) -> Maybe (a, b)
inject_snd (Just b') (a, b) = Just (a, b')
inject_snd Nothing _ = Nothing
```

`replace_snd` replaces the second element of a pair, or returns Nothing if there is no pair:

```
> replace_snd 30 (Just (1, 2))
Just (1,30)
> replace_snd 30 Nothing
Nothing
```

`inject_snd` replaces the second element, or returns Nothing if there is no replacement:

```
> inject_snd (Just 30) (1, 2)
Just (1,30)
> inject_snd Nothing (1, 2)
Nothing
```

Also consider their symmetric counterparts `replace_fst`, `inject_fst` that act on the first element of a pair:

```
replace_fst :: a -> Maybe (a, b) -> Maybe (a, b)
replace_fst x' (Just (x, y)) = Just (x', y)
replace_fst _ Nothing = Nothing

inject_fst :: Maybe a -> (a, b) -> Maybe (a, b)
inject_fst (Just a') (a, b) = Just (a', b)
inject_fst Nothing _ = Nothing
```

My question is this:  **Which of these four functions can be written more compactly** using built-in functions such as monadic operators?  And how?

For example, I've realized that `inject_snd` is just `(mapM . const)`, because `Maybe` is a `Monad` and `((,) a)` is a `Traversable`:

```
> (mapM . const) (Just 30) (1, 2)
Just (1,30)
> (mapM . const) Nothing (1, 2)
Nothing
```

Are there similarly compact equivalents for the other three functions?

Answer (score 3):

```
import Control.Arrow

replaceSnd = fmap . second . const
```

Alternatively `fmap . fmap . const`, which doesn't require the `Arrow` import... but I dislike the `(a,)` functor, and this wouldn't extend to `replaceFst`. With `Arrow` however, it's just as easy:

```
replaceFst = fmap . first . const
```

The `inject`s are a bit more awkward, but can still readily be done with an application-operator section:

```
injectSnd y t = fmap (($ t) . second . const) y
injectFst y t = fmap (($ t) . first . const) y
```

Again, you could replace `second` with `fmap`, but please don't.

This can also be written

```
injectSnd = flip $ \t -> fmap $ ($ t) . second . const
```

Of course, if you're ok with flipping the signature around, then the `flip` is unnecessary:

```
injectSnd' :: (a, b) -> Maybe b -> Maybe (a, b)
injectSnd' t = fmap $ ($ t) . second . const
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and helpful reply!

Comment: `fmap . fmap . const = fmap . (<$)`

Comment: BTW, I personally appreciate the `(a,)` functor, seeing it as "values decorated with `a`". I know it's a bit of a holy war.

Comment: @dfeuer well, that's `Writer`. The problem I have with the `(a,)` monad, and even more with the `(a,)` traversable, is that tuples should intuitively behave symmetrically, but don't. By contrast, nobody expects `Writer` to be symmetric between its arguments.

Answer (score 3):

They can all be rewritten in a compact way. For example `replace_fst` (or `replace_snd`) is a special case of [**`fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fmap):

```
replace_fst :: Functor f => a -> f (a, b) -> f (a, b)
replace_fst c = fmap ((,) c . snd)
```

or we can work with [**`first :: Arrow a => a b c -> a (b, d) (c, d)`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:first):

```
import Control.Arrow(first)

replace_fst :: Functor f => a -> f (a, b) -> f (a, b)
replace_fst c = fmap (first (const c))
```

or more compact:

```
import Control.Arrow(first)

replace_fst :: Functor f => a -> f (a, b) -> f (a, b)
replace_fst = fmap . first . const
```

for example:

```
Prelude Control.Arrow> replace_fst 0 Nothing
Nothing
Prelude Control.Arrow> replace_fst 0 (Just (1,2))
Just (0,2)
```

as for the `inject_fst`, this is the same, except that we now will `fmap` over the first item, so:

```
import Control.Arrow(first)

inject_fst :: Functor f => f a -> (a, b) -> f (a, b)
inject_fst c x = fmap (($ x) . first . const) c
```

we thus perform an `fmap`ing over `c` where, in case `c` is a `Just y`, we will return a `Just (first (const y) x)`, and otherwise if `c` is a `Nothing` return a `Nothing`.

for example:

```
Prelude Control.Arrow> inject_fst Nothing (1,2)
Nothing
Prelude Control.Arrow> inject_fst (Just 0) (1,2)
Just (0,2)
```

These functions do not only work on a `Maybe`, but on a list `[]`, `Tree`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and helpful reply!

Comment: The generalization to `Arrow` doesn't seem to help you here. You can use `first` from `Data.Bifunctor` instead to work with bifunctors other than `(,)`.